# Sketch the graph of the combined function of $y = (g - f)(x)$ for the following functions of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$

Tags: functions, proof-verification

Is this correct? I'd appreciate help if it's not. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost correct.

You can make your graph a little better by making sure it passes through the point $x=2$, $y=-1$.

This is because $f(2)=0$ and $g(2)=-1$, so $(g-f)(2)=-1$.

Comment: Thank you! I missed that one